# How can I show the contents of a file at a specific state of a git repo?

Tags: git

I want to show the contents of a file given by a path at a specific state of a git repo.  I unsuccessfully tried this:

```
git show f825334150cd4bc8f46656b2daa8fa1e92f7796d:Katana/source/Git/GitLocalBranch.h
fatal: ambiguous argument
'f825334150cd4bc8f46656b2daa8fa1e92f7796d:Katana/source/Git/GitLocalBranch.h': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

The commit in question didn't modify the file specified.  How can I show the contents of a file at a given state (specified by a commit hash) regardless of the involvement of the file in the commit?

Answer (score 48):

**It's probably problem with your path specification.**

This works, shows version of Makefile in commit `b1b22df407417...`

```
git show b1b22df407417:Makefile
```

Or current version in master branch

```
git show master:Makefile
```

Or current version in exper branch:

```
git show exper:Makefile
```

Or previous version on the exper branch:

```
git show exper^:Makefile
```

And so on

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it isn't a problem with the path.  I think the problem is that the file wasn't modified by the commit.  I get the same result for any file that wasn't modified by the commit.

Comment: Oh ok, I assumed that you selected specific version because you know that the file was modified in it.

Comment: My problem was that I used an absolute path: `git show <rev>:<absolute path>`.  This answer could be improved by pointing out that one should use the project-relative path, as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2497328/1725151) points out.  That would be useful since this is the top answer.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax you're using matches that shown in the examples for the `git show` manpage, but `git` seems to be hinting that you should specify like this:

```bash
# I _don't_ think this is your answer...
git show f825334150 -- Katana/source/Git/GitLocalBranch.h
```

which I've definitely used for `git log` and is in its manpage.

*My gut, though,* tells me that you using an absolute path and not the path inside the top of your git work tree. You need to make sure that if your `.git` directory is at `Katana/source/Git/.git`, then you chop off everything before the `.git`, like so:

```
git show f825334150:GitLocalBranch.h
```

If you're trying to show a git blob from *outside* the git working area, you need to do something like this:

```
GIT_DIR=Katana/source/Git git show f825334150:GitLocalBranch.h
```

This will tell git where it can find the data for the your repository.

**Bottom line:** double-check your paths and make sure they're right. You might need to set a `GIT_DIR` if you're not running your command from inside the git work area.

Comment: Katana/source/Git/GitLocalBranch.h is a relative path from the base git directory

Comment: Well, that's right, then. Is `f82533` a commit? You can check its type by running `git cat-file -t f82533`.

Comment: Just checked that `git show commitHash:path/to/file` works fine for me when referring to a file not changed in the commit.

Comment: What's the difference between the `:` and the ` -- ` syntax?

Comment: @Moberg `<rev>:<path>` is for `git show`, whereas the usage for `git log` says `git log [<options>] [<revision-range>] [[--] <path>...]`. Looking back, my first blurb about using `--` with `git show` is definitely wrong.